# How to use h.264/h.265 hardware decoding in ffmpeg

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, hardware, video

I know that macOS have h.264/h.265 hardware decoding and encoding support, but I can only find videotoolbox encoder in FFmpeg. Using the same `-c:v h264_videotoolbox` for decoding does not work. Does FFmpeg have support for h.264/h.265 hardware decoding?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm wondering this myself.

Comment: @oarfish No. But apparently other applications like VLC and browsers support it.